# Points in a blowing up determined by an infinitesimal curve not in the centre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Let $\Bbbk$ be a field. Let $A$ be a $\Bbbk$-algebra (commutative and unital). All ring maps are $\Bbbk$-algebra homomorphisms. Let $I\subseteq  A$ be an ideal. Let $X:=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $Z:=\mathrm{Spec}(A/I)$. Let $\widetilde X\to X$ be the blowing up of $X$ along $Z$.

I call a ring map $\varphi:A\to \Bbbk[[t]]$ an *infinitesimal curve* in $X$. Assume $I\not\subseteq \ker(\varphi)$. We can define a $\Bbbk$-point in $\widetilde X$ from $\varphi$.

Write $\varphi=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \varphi_it^i$ for linear maps $\varphi_i:A\to\Bbbk$. Let $k\in\mathbb N$ be such that
$$\varphi_0(I),\cdots,\varphi_{k-1}(I)=0,\quad \varphi_k(I)\ne0.$$
Let $a\in I\setminus \ker(\varphi_k)$. Then there is a ring map
$$A\big[\frac{I}{a}\big]\to \Bbbk,\quad \frac{i_1\cdots i_n}{a^n}\mapsto \frac{\varphi_k(i_1)\cdots\varphi_k(i_n)}{\varphi_k(a)^n}. \tag{$\star$}$$
This defines a $\Bbbk$-point of $\widetilde X$
$$\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk)\to\mathrm{Spec}\Big(A\big[\frac{I}{a}\big]\Big)\subseteq \widetilde X. $$

To check that $(\star)$ is well defined, I need the following fact.

> Let $n\in\mathbb N_+$. Let $i_1,\cdots,i_n,j_1,\cdots,j_n\in I$. If $i_1\cdots i_n=j_1\cdots j_n\in A$, then $\varphi_k(i_1)\cdots\varphi_k(i_n)=\varphi_k(j_1)\cdots\varphi_k(j_n)$.

Here is a short proof.

> Since $\varphi:A\to\Bbbk[[t]]$ preserves multiplication, we have
> $$\varphi_{kn}(f_1\cdots f_n)=\sum_{\substack{\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_n\geq0\\\mu_1+\cdots+\mu_n=kn}}\varphi_{\mu_1}(f_1)\cdots\varphi_{\mu_n}(f_n). $$
> Then
> $$\varphi_{kn}(i_1\cdots i_n)=\sum_{\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_n}\varphi_{\mu_1}(i_1)\cdots\varphi_{\mu_n}(i_n)\\=\varphi_k(i_1)\cdots\varphi_k(i_n)$$
> where all summands but one are zero, because $k\in\mathbb N$ is the minimum such that $\varphi_k(I)\ne0$. Similar equality holds for $j_1,\cdots,j_n$. Therefore
> $$\varphi_k(i_1)\cdots\varphi_k(i_n)=\varphi_{kn}(i_1\cdots i_n)=\varphi_{kn}(j_1\cdots j_n)=\varphi_k(j_1)\cdots\varphi_k(j_n). $$

Note that in the proof we need $\varphi:A\to \Bbbk[[t]]$ to have codomain $\Bbbk[[t]]$ even only $\varphi_k$ is used in $(\star)$.

Here are my questions:

1. Fix $k\in\mathbb N$. Let $\phi:A\to\Bbbk[t]/t^{k+1}$ be a ring map such that $\phi_0(I),\cdots,\phi_{k-1}(I)=0$ and $\phi_k(I)\ne0$. Can we define a point in $\widetilde X$?
2. In the question above, if we can lift $\phi:A\to\Bbbk[t]/t^{k+1}$ to $\phi':A\to \Bbbk[[t]]$, then $\phi'$ defines a point in $\widetilde X$. This point does not depend on how we lift $\phi$ to $\phi'$. Then, in which situation can we lift $\phi$?
3. Can all $\Bbbk$-points in $\widetilde X$ be realized via some $\varphi:A\to \Bbbk[[t]]$? What are conditions on $(A,I)$ for an affirmative answer?

Comment: Do you assume that $X$ and $Z$ are smooth, or do you allow them to be singular? The answers for 1 and 2 should be positive in the smooth case, but negative in the singular case in the generality stated. I can say more depending on which case you care about!

Comment: @DevlinMallory I see when $A$ is smooth over $\Bbbk$, we have an affirmative ansower for 2, thus for 1. I do not see how we need smoothness of $Z=\mathrm{Spec(A/I)}$. I think smoothness of $X$ is too strong. I would like some particular condition on $\phi:A\to \Bbbk[t]/t^{k+1}$ for liftability, such as some obstruction classes.